# Custom getter on entity model?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have an Entity with a Date property and want to create a boolean property to check if that Date is in the future or not.

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

public virtual bool IsUpcoming {
    get
    {
        return Date >= DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run a Get on it, it throws this error:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Where(s => s.IsUpcoming)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'IsUpcoming' on entity type 'Show' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information

Any tips on why/how would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [NotMapped] attribute

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual bool IsUpcoming {
    get
    {
        return Date >= DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

or Ignore if you use fluent api

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Show>().Ignore(c => c.IsUpComing);
```

but you will be able to use it after you get the DB set to your application( usually after ToList()). If you try to use it in a Linq query to get data from DB you will get the exception you have got already.